# Por que me sale undefined cuando intento agregar una propiedad del objeto

Tags: javascript

Hola como están? Les quería hacer una consulta, esto haciendo una biblbioteca de peliculas y cuando quiero agregar una tarjeta desde el innerHTML para poner mis peliculas me coloca undefined, que estoy haciendo mal???

```js
const peliculas = [
{
    nombre: "En la Mira",
    categoria: "Suspenso",
    precio: 500,
    descripcion:"En la mira es una película de suspenso y drama. Sigue la historia de un empleado en un call center que se ve amenazado de muerte mediante una llamada de un consumidor al que no le dan la baja del servicio",
    imagen:"../img/enlamira.jpg"

},
{
    nombre: "Actividad Paranormal",
    categoria: "Terror",
    precio: 600,
    descripcion:"Cuando una joven pareja de clase media se muda a lo que parece ser la típica casa de barrio periférico, empieza a ser perturbada por una presencia, maligna, que se muestra especialmente activa durante las noches.",
    imagen:"../img/actividadparanormal.jpg"
},
]
const tarjetaPelis = document.getElementById("peliculas")

        tarjetaPelis.innerHTML = 
        `<div class="peli1"><img src${peliculas.imagen} alt="pel1" class="img1">
        <b><h3 class="h3">${peliculas.nombre}</h3></b>
        <p>${peliculas.descripcion}</p>
        <div class="plataformas">
        <h3> $${peliculas.precio}</h3>
        </div>`
```

Comment: peliculas tal como lo declaraste es un array con 2 objetos. Pero a la hora de crear la plantilla con innerHTML no veo que uses indices en ninguna parte, si quisieras acceder al precio de la pelicula 1 deberias poner peliculas[0].precio por ejemplo, y si quisieras saber el precio de la 2da deberias poner peliculas[1].precio

Comment: nono, quiero que haga una "card" con el precio, el nombre, la descripcion, etc de cada pelicula del array

Comment: @Francisco amigo, lo que dice ElFuturo Llego es correcto, obtienes un `undefined` porque estas accediendo directamente al arreglo de peliculas e intentando acceder a una propiedad `nombre`/`imagen` que no existen, como el ya ha dicho, se trata de un arreglo, por lo cual debes indicar las pocisiones de memoria, para ello entonces y que te funcione bien debes usar un cilclo, te recomiendo un `for`,  un `for of` o un `forEach`.

Comment: Otro punto a tener en cuenta es que al usar `innerHTML = ` estas cambiando o reemplazando todo el contenido de tarjeta de peliculas, lo cual genera un resultado indeseado, debes usar una concatenacion en este caso para que el contenido no se sobreescriba si no que se adicione `innerHTML +=`.